# Epson V350 Scanner on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, usb, 17.10, scanner

I've tried everything that I can find to get my scanner working again. It worked fine with 16.04 and now that I've upgraded to 17.10 I can't get it working again. I know that I had problems before, but having tried every solution that I can find on the web, I'm going to ask here for help.

The device is plugged in via a USB hub (I've tried everything directly too) but whilst I can find it in devices, it won't run with iscan or xsane.

lsusb can see it
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 04b8:012f Seiko Epson Corp. GT-F700 [Perfection V350]

All help gratefully received.

Comment: so you would have downloaded iscan-gt-f700-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz from here? http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-f700&version=1.0.0

Comment: I have the same issue and have downloaded drivers from here http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-f720&version=1.0.1 to no avail

Comment: I'm also trying to get the Epson v350 working on Ubuntu. Currently 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I've found a more-or-less working solution, I post it here so maybe someone could improve it.

It works with xsane, not with iscan.

What happens is that it takes a lot to start and the preview window shows up blank.

So:

- I've added in the file `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` the line

  ```
  usb 0x04b8 0x0131
  ```

  where the codes are taken from `lsusb`
- (I know very little about udev rules) I've added a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-epson.rules`

  ```
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8",ATTRS{idProduct}=="0131",ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
  ```

  ENV{libsane_matched}=="yes",RUN+="/bin/setfacl -m g:scanner:rw $env{DEVNAME}"
- my user is clearly in the group scanner.

  And I launch xsane with a `LIBRARY_PATH` (modifying `ld.so.conf.d` messes up everything)

  ```
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/sane xsane
  ```
- So after some  time (200 secs) an xsane dialog windows pops up, I choose the third line (the one with the name of the scanner):

  [image: xsane dialog window]

Finally xsane starts, sometimes with a uncomplete preview window (blank with no button or frame to set), but it works.

Hope it helps.